# bat - файл. Не пойму почему не работает

Tags: bat

Есть такой участок `bat` файла:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in (..\about.me) do @echo %%a %%b "Studyin" %%c
```

И Файл `about.me`

```
+--------+
|Name    |
|College |
+--------+
```

Хочу получить вывод: `Name studyin College`
. А получаю `Name studyin College study in`
.     Вопрос: почему? Что сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Цикл for проходит по строкам файла. В данном файле две строки, поэтому получается две итерации цикла. В каждой итерации в переменную %a попадает единственный токен, он и выводится, а за ним слово Studyin. %b и %c остаются пустыми.

Если в файле about написать что-то вроде:

> NameA CollegeA
>   NameB CollegeB

а батник подправить следующим образом:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in (about.me) do @echo %%a Studyin %%b
```

то получится вывод:

> NameA Studyin CollegeA
>   NameB Studyin CollegeB